# Why are user thumbnails not showing up for other people using my script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have created a user directory web app concept that pulls user images, names, and email addresses within G-Suite. I'm generating a Google Sheet with the data and displaying that data through an HTML table. All the data pulls over into the table cells as intended, including the thumbnails on my end. However, when another admin uses the application, the thumbnails show up as the default "head and shoulders" image. I have all my permissions set so anyone in the domain can use it, so I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with permissions on the application or the sheet. If anyone has any incite as to why the `user.thumbnailPhotoUrl` is not giving the user's images it would be very much appreciated. It might also be worth noting that I added all the profile pictures myself through the admin panel. My supervisor updated his profile picture and was only able to see his own.

Here is the code I am using:

code.gs

```
    function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("table3");
  }
  function getDomainUsersList() {
var users = [];
  var options = {
    domain: "my_domain",     // Google Apps domain name
    customer: "my_customer",
    maxResults: 100,
    projection: "basic",      // Fetch basic details of users
    viewType: "domain_public",
    orderBy: "email"          // Sort results by users
  }
  do {
    var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(options);
    response.users.forEach(function(user) {
      users.push([user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail, user.thumbnailPhotoUrl]);
    });

    // For domains with many users, the results are paged
    if (response.nextPageToken) {
      options.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    }
  } while (response.nextPageToken);

  // Insert data in a spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nzRcC8ChbY2C0wjTY_hC0txkYMphMofvxyHws86syfM/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Users") || ss.insertSheet("Users", 1);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,users.length, users[0].length).setValues(users);
var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
return data;
}

/**function getData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nzRcC8ChbY2C0wjTY_hC0txkYMphMofvxyHws86syfM/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Users") || ss.insertSheet("Users", 1);
var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
return data;
```

table3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  <style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
border-color: blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Employee Directory</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th id="header">Picture</th>
    <th id="header" onclick="sortTable(1)">Name</th>
    <th id="header" onclick="sortTable(2)">Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
  
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  <script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getDomainUsersList();
});
function generateTable(dataArray) {

dataArray.forEach(function(r){
var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");
var row = document.createElement("tr");
var col1 = document.createElement("td");
col1.textContent = r[0];
var col2 = document.createElement("td");
col2.textContent = r[1];
var col3 = document.createElement("td");
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = r[2];
col3.appendChild(image);
row.appendChild(col3);
row.appendChild(col1);
row.appendChild(col2);
tbody.appendChild(row);
});

}
</script>
<!--Sortable Headers -->
<script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,

Isaac

Comment: Can you share the code? What did you set at "Execute as" when you deployed the WebApp?

Comment: I added my code to the above post. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This could be related to the configuration. Have you tried to contact [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I opened an issue with Google. Can you star it for visibility?

Answer (score 0):

@IMTheNachoMan reported the issue in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/160510853). You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to his report.